# Can I use "it" in place of "that" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

[Naruto](http://gogoanime.io/naruto-episode-147)

In the video, the anime says

> Why don't you show me what the true power is, and defeat me with that.

I am wondering, is it possible to use **it** in place of **that** and still the sentence remaining grammatical?

Comment: Yes, you can. Both pronouns would be anaphoric to the noun phrase "what the true power is", but unlike dummy pronoun "it", the independent demonstrative "that" is 'fused' and means "that x" ( x = "what the true power is").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can replace **that** with **it**, and it will still be grammatical.

There are two possible reasons for the writer using **that** rather than **it**.

Firstly, **that** can be emphatic, whereas it is difficult to make **it** emphatic:

> I don't want it. - *unemphatic*
>   I don't want **that**! - *emphatic*.

A famous example of the emphatic use of **that** is in Bill Clinton's statement:

> I did not have sexual relations with **that** woman!

Secondly, it suggests that there is something else, a **this**.

> I don't want this, I want **that**!

Comment: Also, saying "true power" in place of "the true power" will be correct?In the video, it says, A:Your   power is not true power. B:Why don't you show me what **the** true power is, and defeat me with that.?

Comment: There are many things that could be regarded as true power: economic, military, political, etc. The speaker has one specific true power in mind, so he or she uses the definite article "**the** true power". So omitting **the**  would be grammatically correct, but not what the speaker meant.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, both the sentences are correct .  However, the nuance is that *it*, referring to the  word 
'power",  is quite  neutral, whereas *that* emphasizes the special interest in what might happen when that power was used.
[Here's the source](http://www.myhappyenglish.com/free-english-lesson/2014/01/22/it-vs-that-in-grammar-conversation-english-lesson/).